# Theme import not changing the color scheme

Tags: theming, 8

I created a new theme in d8 and modified some color schemes.

Then I ported that theme to another site and placed in `/var/www-
drupal/themes` and enabled it.

The theme is ported. But the changes made to 
the color scheme is not ported. Any idea **how to import the color scheme**?

Its still in the default color scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export the color configuration from the old site and import it to the new site.

You can do this in UI. Go to */admin/config/development/configuration/single/export*, select configuration type `Simple configuration` and the configuration name `color.theme.mytheme`. Copy and paste the color configuration to the new site. Use here the single item import section.

If you want to do this automatically when installing the theme you can place the file `color.theme.mytheme.yml` in the `/config/install` folder of the theme.